# JobIntentService for Oreo and pre Oreo

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

Anyone have worked with JobIntentservice for O oreo and pre O. I read more about the JobIntentService from the developer.android.com  but they have not  mention the complete example for this.

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Service/JobIntentService

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JobIntentService is very similar to IntentService, where "onHandleWork" will be called which indicates that Service has been started to perform the work.
Check [THIS](https://android.jlelse.eu/keep-those-background-services-working-when-targeting-android-oreo-sdk-26-cbf6cc2bdb7f) for Converting to JobIntentService

Comment: Add some description here

Comment: JobIntentService works in the same way as a Service however it enqueues the work into the JobScheduler on compatible Android targets. Check [THIS][1] for detail info

  [1]: https://android.jlelse.eu/keep-those-background-services-working-when-targeting-android-oreo-sdk-26-cbf6cc2bdb7f

Comment: JobIntentService sounds perfect, except that you can't actually cancel a job (from what I can tell).

Comment: Can the user stop the use of JobIntentService for any particular app from the settings? @Rhonage